# How to pass data from an native application (AdiIRC, an IRC client) to my Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I use Chrome 79 and and Nodejs 13, in windows 10.

I also use an IRC client, AdiIRC, to connect to some IRC channel. This program can call external programs with arguments via its scripting language (via [Run](https://dev.adiirc.com/projects/adiirc/wiki/Run) and [$exec](https://dev.adiirc.com/projects/adiirc/wiki/$exec) ).

So, what I want to do is, probably using Native Messaging, **whenever a specific message appears in the IRC channel,
it to be passed as argument from AdiIRC to my Chrome extension**, most probably via something like:  `Run \path\to\some_executable.exe %message`
*where "some_executable.exe" would send the wanted message data (using stdout) to the extension* .

**So, my question is, how can I pass data from AdiIRC to my Chrome extension? Is it possible?**
*Am I entirely missing something regarding the Native Messaging concept, and so, what I want to do is possible via a different way??*

Below is my effort, i.e. my Chrome extension and a native messaging host.

Note:  in Google's [Native Messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), at some point is says that:

> Chrome starts each native messaging host in a separate process and
>   communicates with it using standard input (stdin) and standard output
>   (stdout).

So, from what I understand from that, 
in order to be able to pass data from AdiIRC to my extension whenever needed, I need AdiIRC to manually launch **another instance** of `NativeMessaging.js` .
So, to test my theory, I launched `node "C:\MDN\app\NativeMessaging.js"` manually, outside of Chrome (after loading my extension in Chrome), and tried entering random test text inside it,  but unfortunately they are not received in my extension's background.html page|Console .

background.js (of my Chrome extension) :

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('my_messaging_host');

port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  console.log("Received: " + message);
});
```

Native Messaging host setup:

install-host.bat

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\my_messaging_host" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0my_messaging_host.json" /f
```

my_messaging_host.json

```
{
  "name": "my_messaging_host",
  "description": "Example host for native messaging",
  "path": "C:\\MDN\\app\\my_messaging_host_win.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://(my extension's hash)/"
  ]
}
```

my_messaging_host_win.bat

```sh
node "C:\MDN\app\NativeMessaging.js"
```

NativeMessaging.js  ( NodeJS code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#App_side) )

```js
#!/usr/local/bin/node

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    var input = [];
    var chunk;
    while (chunk = process.stdin.read()) {
        input.push(chunk);
    }
    input = Buffer.concat(input);

    var msgLen = input.readUInt32LE(0);
    var dataLen = msgLen + 4;

    if (input.length >= dataLen) {
        var content = input.slice(4, dataLen);
        var json = JSON.parse(content.toString());
        handleMessage(json);
    }
});

function sendMessage(msg) {
    var buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg));

    var header = Buffer.alloc(4);
    header.writeUInt32LE(buffer.length, 0);

    var data = Buffer.concat([header, buffer]);
    process.stdout.write(data);
}

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    sendMessage({error: err.toString()});
});
```

*Possible addition to NativeMessaging.js, in case it's to be run with an argument:*
*e.g. via `node NativeMessaging.js messageToSend`*

```js
sendMessage(process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: The nativeMessaging API flow currently is that the extension is always the initiator of the comm cycle. The thing you want is currently being developed in https://crbug.com/967262. Meanwhile you might be better off writing a simple utility that accumulates data from IRC and that listens on some TCP port for periodic checks by an extension via XMLHttpRequest or fetch. Or you could use a persistent webSocket connection.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the detailed reply! 
Regarding the approaches you suggested: unfortunately they seem not suitable for me, mostly because I want to pass data from the program to my extension immediately, i.e. right at the moment the relevant IRC event occurs, and also because they are difficult for me to implement.
So it appears I have to wait for that Chrome issue to finish being developed.

Comment: I thought a WebSocket connection would allow for immediate two-way communication.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I was referring to that approach as not suitable, because it requires creating and connecting to a server,
but, there seems no way to make AdiIRC act as a server, nor connect AdiIRC and my extension via WebSocket directly(=without a server). 
In any case, AdiIRC client is awesome, and I just want to find a way to connect it with my extension -- I don't want to replace the native messaging host with some standalone script (that I would write in NodeJS together with some npm IRC package) that would connect to the IRC channel and send matching messages to my extension.